# ERROR: (gcloud.docker) Docker is not installed

Tags: gcloud, coreos

I'm running CoreOS alpha v815.0.0 from within GCE and trying to pull image from my private Google Container Registry. And here's the error:

```
$ gcloud docker pull gcr.io/agency-revolution/node:4.1.0-2-onbuild
ERROR: (gcloud.docker) Docker is not installed.
```

Gcloud version:

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.79

alpha 2015.08.17
app 2015.09.23
beta 2015.08.17
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2015.09.23
core-nix 2015.09.03
gcloud 2015.09.21
gsutil 4.15
gsutil-nix 4.14
```

Note that I already logged in successfully with `gcloud auth login`.
Would appriciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the GCE CoreOS images, `gcloud` is a shortcut for `docker run -t -i google/cloud-sdk gcloud`. That is, because you cannot install `gcloud` on CoreOS directly, it runs inside a container based on the `google/cloud-sdk` image. This container does not have `docker` installed.

You'll need to install the docker CLI tool onto this image (it's based on Debian Wheezy, so [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/debian/#debian-wheezy-stable-7-x-64-bit) will be helpful). Then, configure `docker` to talk to the docker daemon in the host CoreOS machine.

Comment: So I have to build another image based on `google/cloud-sdk` to install docker CLI? But how to configure so that gcloud could run on my image?

Comment: Wonder why there's no documentation for working with `gcloud` on CoreOS

Comment: What do you mean by "how to configure so that gcloud could run on my image?" If you base your image on `google/cloud-sdk`, gcloud will be installed. Working with gcloud on CoreOS is like working with any tool on CoreOS; what specifically needs documentation? I do agree that it would be handy to have docker pre-installed.

Comment: For example, suppose I build an image `quyen/cloud-sdk` that based on `google/cloud-skd` to install docker, but when I run `gcloud docker pull...`, it is actually `docker run -t -i google/cloud-sdk gcloud docker pull..` while it suppose to be `docker run -t -i quyen/cloud-sdk gcloud docker pull...`

Comment: `gcloud` is just a convenience wrapper; it's defined in `/etc/profile.d/google-cloud-sdk.sh` as `gcloud="(docker images google/cloud-sdk || docker pull google/cloud-sdk) > /dev/null;docker run -t -i --net="
host" -v $HOME/.config:/.config -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock google/cloud-sdk gcloud"`. Feel free to make a similar shell alias on your CoreOS machine.